# How to do Layout with Microsoft FAST controls

Tags: aurelia, web-controls, fluent-ui

until now I have used Bootstrap for building my sites.
I heard about Microsoft FAST web-controls, and I want to try it but there is no layout grid.
How am I supposed to do layouting in MS FAST?
I am no web designer, this is why I use bootstrap templates.
I also use Aurelia as my framework of choice to build web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to how are you supposed to do layouting is "there is no how". It's up to you.
What FAST offers is some building blocks (@microsoft/fast-foundation) to allow you to implement **your custom**  design system. So you could go on using bootstrap or turn to material design or another choice.

Here's the link to the info supporting this answer: https://www.fast.design/docs/introduction/#how-can-fast-help-me

Regards.